# Odoo decorations in tree view not working?

Tags: treeview, odoo, decoration

I am trying to add decorations in an inherited tree view in odoo 13. For this I added a variable in my module

```
x_LCStatus = fields.Selection(selection=[('0', 'In development'),('1', 'Active'), 
   ('2', 'Not for new developments'), ('3', 'End of life')], string='Life cycle', 
   default='1', store=True)
```

However, when I try to change the decoration in the associated tree view nothing changes from the default settings.

```
<xpath expr="//tree" position="attributes">
      <attribute name="decoration-danger">"x_LCStatus=='3'"</attribute>
      <attribute name="decoration-warning">"x_LCStatus=='2'"</attribute>
      <attribute name="decoration-primary">"x_LCStatus=='1'"</attribute>
</xpath>
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: ```<xpath expr="//tree[@string='Contacts']" position="attributes"> OR <xpath expr="//tree[1]" position="attributes">``` Have you tried exact tree path?

Comment: Try to remove the double quotes

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Actually removing the double quotes showed that I did not include ```x_LCStatus``` in the view yet. So after having taken care of this I tried both ```<xpath expr="//tree[1]" position="attributes">``` (with success) and <xpath expr="//tree[@string='Product']" position="attributes">```. The later one raises the error message: ""View inheritance may not use attribute 'string' as a selector.". 

This said - I still could not resolve the problem ...

Comment: For when it's still relevant: use `name` instead of `string` to identify the tree.